# How to embed out of vocab words at the time of testing in word2vec model?

Tags: nlp, word2vec, word-embedding, oov

I was training my word2vec model (skip-gram) on a vocab size of 100 000. But at the time of testing I got few words which weren't in the vocab. To find their embeddings I tried 2 approaches:

1. Calculate minimum edit distance word from vocab and acquire its embedding.
2. Constructed different n-grams from the word and searched them in the vocab.

Despite of applying these methods, I am not able to get rid of out of vocab words problem completely.

Does word2vec take all n-grams of a word into account while training like fastText does?

Note - In fastText if our input word is quora then it considers all of its possible n-grams in the corpus.

[image: https://www.quora.com/How-does-fastText-output-a-vector-for-a-word-that-is-not-in-the-pre-trained-model]

Answer (score 0):

I would assume that the out-of-vocabulary words in your case were very rare ones. One of the possibilities is to use hash of designated symbol (or another very rare word) as a sentinel for such out-of-vocabulary words. This requires preprocessing such words but should be good enough in a practical application.

Comment: You mean to say if I have a vocabulary of 1 Lakh, I should start indexing of vocabs from 1 to 1-Lakh, and keep an index 0 for rare words right?

Comment: Yes, you could use 0 index for the purpose of catching all rare (non-vocabulary) words. It does not matter if it is going to be index 0 (any index would be good).

Comment: If you find the answer useful could you please mark it as such?